# Transcendence of $e^{\frac{\pi^2}{12 \log 2}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

Is it known whether $e^{\frac{\pi^2}{12 \log 2}}$ is transcendental or algebraic?

This number showed up in [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259718/limit-of-denominator-in-continued-fraction-expansion-algebraic).

Comment: I thought this question was undecided for $e^\pi$, why would $e^{\frac{\pi^2}{12 \log 2}}$ be any simpler?

Comment: exp(pi) is transcendental by Gelfond-Schneider: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

Comment: For $e^{\pi}$ it is known, but I would be surprised if this one was known...

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question ?

Comment: @Sylvain, there was a question maybe yesterday about algebraic non-examples of a result of Levy on continued fractions, and this question came up there. (But OP should have linked to it)

Comment: $e^\pi=(-1)^{-i}$ so it's transcendental. The open one is $\pi^e$ but I don't think that $\pi^e$ has some profound meaning, it's just something that looks as silly as $e^\pi$.

Comment: =3.275822918721811159787681882453843863608475525982374149405198924190723215644960355... Clearly trascendental! :)

Comment: Perhaps this number could be fed into one of those calculators that takes decimals and tries to find integer polynomials they satisfy.

Answer (score 11):

This is most likely open, since alredy $e^{\pi^2}$ is not known to be transcendental.

As an added difficulty, I don't think that $\frac{\pi^2}{12 \log 2}$ is known to be transcendental either.

There are very few, very limited, tricks to prove this kind of result: things like taking $(-1)^{-i}$ and $i^i$ and applying Gelfond–Schneider, or building the Weierstrass $\wp$-function of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ to get the transcendence of $e^{\pi\sqrt{d}}$ from its invariants.

Comment: If $\pi^2/12\log 2$ were algebraic, its exponential would be transcendental, so I don't see why it's a difficulty :P